# How to create a static page in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Currently am creating one auction website using cakephp. It have a menu bar like about us, contact us. I have created only the default page. So i want to create those pages. advice me how to create.

Answer (score 7):

Old thread, but I found it while trying to do the same in 2.x.

Jack's answer is correct, with a small typo.  It should be

`Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about'));`

Hopefully this helps someone else, as it did me.

Answer (score 4):

Create an `about.ctp` in the `/app/views/pages/` folder.

Then add `Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about'));` in the `/app/config/routes.php` file.  You should be able to access it at `www.yoursite.com/about`

Comment: I have created the file blog.ctp in /app/views/pages/ folder. Also i have the comments, Router::connect('/blog/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'blog')); in to /app/config/routes.php. But still am not getting the page.

Comment: Are you getting a blank page?

Comment: I followed your instructions however it didn't work. An error about controller was shown. Instead of using '/about/' in the first argument, use '/about'. Just drop the second slash.

Answer (score 3):

## Since the new version of cakephp is freshly out, I'm adding this answer to deal with the newer version (3.x).

To link to a static page you still use the [PageController](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html) but the code slightly changed.

Here the code you would need in the 3.x version

```
$routes->connect('/about', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about']);
```

You can read more about the new [routing system here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html).

*I have no affiliation with cakephp. I added this answer since I found this post while searching how to do this in 3.0*

Answer (score 2):

[Read more here](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/10/creating-static-pages-in-cakephp.html)

Method 1: if you want to create content pages like about us, privacy policy which contents can be changed by an admin interface follow these steps

Step1: Change pagesController

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('content');//to allow to be visible for non-logged in users, if you are using login system
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
public function content($id = null, $layout = null, $theme=null) {
    if ($layout) $this->layout = $layout;//if you are using mulitple layouts and themes and want to change it dynamicaly
    if ($theme) $this->theme = $theme;

    $this->set('content', $this->Page->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Page.id' => $id))));
     $this->Page->id= $id;
     $this->set('title_for_layout', $this->Page->field('title'));

}
```

}

Step 2: add a table content with fields you need like id, title, content, image, theme,layout etc.
Step 3: In View/Pages add content.ctp

```
 <div class="row innerPage">    
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="row userInfo">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <h1 class=" text-left border-title"> <?php echo $content['Page']['title'];?> </h1>
      <div class="w100 clearfix">
        <?php echo $content['Page']['content'];?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However you can change html according to your need, I prefer bootstrap framework.

Then you can use it as

```
<?php echo $this->html->link("Terms of Services", array("controller" => "pages", "action" => "content", 5), array("class" => 'themeprimary','target'=>'_blank')) ?>
```

This will generate a link yoursite/pages/content/5. 5 is the id of row you want to show the details of.

If you want your link like yoursite/terms then you need one more step to go. In routes.php  add this line.

```
Router::connect('/terms', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'content',5));
```

Method 2: You simply need to display content without any database
Step1 :Just create a about.ctp under View/Pages and put the content you want to display
Step 2: Change your pagesController. add a method about

```
public function about($layout = null) {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'About');    
}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pages controller](http://book.cakephp.org/view/958/The-Pages-Controller) for this purpose.

Creating views at `APP/views/pages/` with names such as `about_us.ctp` and `contact_us.ctp` will allow you to access them at the url:

`www.site.com/pages/about_us`

you can then change how these URIs look with routing.

Comment: have you modified the pages_controller?

Comment: @raultm: you shouldn't have to modify the pages controller at all.

Comment: @Anh Pham it's not recommened but possible though. @Rathika Jeganathan did you change routes in `app/config/routes.php` ?

Comment: @Anh Pham I know, that's the reason of my question.